# Aplicar tamanho em um textarea, exceto se ele possuir o atributo "rows"

Tags: html, css3, textarea

Tenho um `textarea` que está formatado com a seguinte regra:

```css
.wm-form textarea{
  min-height:100px;
  resize: vertical;
  width:100%;
  border-radius:4px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<form class="wm-form">
  <textarea></textarea>
</form>
```

Porém eu gostaria que, quando meu `textarea` tivesse o atributo `rows` (que afetaria o tamanho do `textarea`), o tamanho definido em `min-height` seja aplicado.

Como fazer isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use o [`not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/:not) para fazer uma seleção pela textarea que não possui o atributo `rows`:

```css
.wm-form textarea {
  resize: vertical;
  border-radius:4px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  width:100%
}

.wm-form textarea:not([rows]){
  min-height:100px;
}
```

```html
<form class="wm-form">
  <textarea></textarea>
</form>

<form class="wm-form">
  <textarea rows='10'></textarea>
</form>
```